# Expand/Collapse Table - align nested data with main table columns

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, tablerow

I want to expand rows in my table & have the data in the expanded pieces align with my main table columns. (example in photo 1)
[I want my expand/collapse data to align as it does in this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sO5mo.png)

I can't seem to get the data aligned. It ends up being skewed. (example in photo 2)
[misaligned rows inside the  element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkOyl.png)

(sorry, I don't have enough reputation points to include the images themselves in this post)

Comment: Welcome to the StackOverflow platform, could you provide us some code or a minimal, reproducible example so we can work from? That would be greatly appreciated and easier to help you out

Comment: Here's a code sandbox. I've just hard-coded example data within the `<Collapse>` to show how it's misaligned with the main columns. https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-y8uhl?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&file=/demo.js